# (Classical) Probability distribution of momentum for a harmonic oscillator (Griffiths problem 1.12)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, probability

I am trying to solve problem 1.12 in Griffith's *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, but when I compare my answer to the solutions online it is wrong. We want to find the probability distribution of momentum as a classical harmonic oscillator goes from minimum to maximum $x$. So far I have the following:

Overall we want to find $\frac{dt}{T}$, the probability that we find the system at time $t+dt$ in terms of the corresponding momentum $p$ and $dp$. The total energy is $$E =\frac{p^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}kx^2,$$ so $x$ in terms of $p$ is $$x = \pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{k}(E-\frac{p^2}{2m})}.$$ Now the force is $\frac{dp}{dt} = -kx$ which we have found so $$dt =\frac{dp}{\sqrt{2k(E-\frac{p^2}{2m})}}.$$ We know the total time $T$ is that for half a cycle ($\pi\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}$) so $\frac{dt}{T}$ should be $$\frac{dp}{\pi\sqrt{2mE-p^2}}.$$ If someone could spot what I did wrong here I would really appreciate it. Also I took the negative square root to keep the probability positive, but a more physical reason would be appreciated.

The problem for reference:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain more about the exercise?

Comment: This question is nearly unanswerable until the exercise is more fully explained.

Comment: @schris38, I have now added the problem so you can see

Comment: @DanielSank I have now added the problem so you can see

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563/168783), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/479421) instead.

Comment: The problem is pretty clear.  It asks you to compute $1/v(x) T$.  So, instead of solving for $x$ in terms of $p$, why not solve for $v$ in terms of $x$ instead?  Then you're done.

Comment: How do you contrast your answer with the target expression? Can you reexpress it in terms of $p_{max}$?